# jquery add class to parent on input focus

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a contact form. I want to add class to parent div of the input box on the input:focus.
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nEHzn/) . I want that not just the input box but the div background color should change to purple on the input focus.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="round">
    <div class="round_label">name</div>
    <input type="text" class="round_text">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".round_text:focus").parent().css('background', '#8b66ac');
    $('.round_text:focus').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.round {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F3;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 440px;
}
.round_text:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8b66ac;
}
.round_label {
    border-right: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
    color: #B6B6B6;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 156px;
}
.round_text {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F3F3F3;
    border: medium none;
    color: #424242;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 240px;
}
```

---

Also, Can you help me as if i need to add two properties eg:

```
$(".round_text").focus(function(){
       $(this).parent().css('background', '#8b66ac','color','#fff');

  }).blur(function(){
       $(this).parent().css('background', /*color*/);
  })
```

Comment: Always add your code in question, along with jsfiddle link

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will do so from next time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add class instead and give the style

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $(".text").focus(function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass("round");
   $(this).parent().addClass("bluebg");

  }).blur(function(){
       $(this).parent().removeClass("bluebg");
   $(this).parent().addClass("round");
  })

});    

.bluebg {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8b66ac;
color:#623886;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without jQuery?

Answer (score 10):

Use focus event

```
  $(".round_text").focus(function(){
       $(this).parent().css('background', '#8b66ac');

  }).blur(function(){
       $(this).parent().css('background', /*color*/);
  })
```

EDIT: Alternate solution using toggleClass()

CSS

```
.round_text:focus, .round.is_focused {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8b66ac;
}
```

JS

```
$(".round_text").on('focus blur', function(){
     $(this).parent().toggleClass('is_focused');
})
```

Comment: Perfect Answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 $("input").on("focus",function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("any_class").css("background","purple");
    });
```

Comment: why add class AND use css() method?

Comment: i have read title where op want to add class to parent and in description he want to set background to purple therefore i set both

Answer (score 3):

If I am getting your question right,

You are selecting `focused` elements, but you need to change css of  parent `div` on `focus` event.

Do this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".round_text").focus(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('background', '#8b66ac');
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BcAM/1/)